# Creating a graph from a data set with a dynamic number of columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a spreadsheet to automatically generate a graph from multiple  data sets that are brought across from a csv file. This data will not have a specific number of rows or columns, but the X-axis value will always be in column D. I'd like to use every column after D for a separate series of Y-axis values, with a loop that ends when it hits a blank column.
I'd like my Graph to be on a separate sheet labelled "graph", while my data is still on the sheet "data".

I've tried to create ranges to use with an indirect function, but as far as I'm aware its not compatible with the graph making function.

```
 Sub Macro4()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Data!$E$1"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Data!$D:$D"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Data!$E:$E"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Data!$F$1"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=Data!$D:$D"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Data!$F:$F"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "=Data!$G$1"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=Data!$D:$D"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = "=Data!$G:$G"
End Sub
```

I want it to give an output graph like this does, but on a loop to detect first blank column, and create data series on the graph up to that point.
thanks

Comment: For some reason it stopped working, I retyped it and it began working again, not exactly sure why, sorry

Comment: That's fine. If there is another problem, *Don't take it out on this answer*; it's another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straightforward using R1C1:

```vb
Sub Macro 4()
Dim i As Long, LCol As Long, c As Object, s As String
LCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
s = "=Data!$D:$D"
Set c = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers).Chart
For i = 5 To LCol
    With c.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "=Data!$R1C" & i
        .XValues = s
        .Values = "=Data!$C" & i
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```